# Error message: ./src/firebase.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase'

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am getting the following Error message: ./src/firebase.js Module not found: Can't resolve
I 'firebase'

I am using firebase version firebase@9.0.2

Command in firebase.js import firebase from "from firebase";

Answer (score 4):

In the 9.x version of the SDK you no longer can import the entire `firebase` object, but instead import individual functions. For more on this see the Firebase documentation on [adding Firebase to your web app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), which shows this as the starting point:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Alternatively you can keep using the older call style with the latest SDK, by using its compat imports:

```
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

I also recommend checking out the documentation on [upgrading to the modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade), as most tutorials on others sites are likely going to be using the older style calls.